# Setting text with spinner is not working for only one item from my list, how to resolve?

Tags: android

I have a problem with the code below, I have a spinner that has the names of three poets and when one is picked, it sets the content of the second spinner and when a poem is selected from the second spinner that sets the text view contents to the poem.  This works for every single one except the Judgment of Paris poem which when chose does nothing, can anyone see why?

this is the name of the string copy and pasted

```
string name="judgement"
```

code:

```
    // defining variables
  Spinner PoetSpinner, PoemSpinner;
  String Poets[] = { "", "Robert Burns", "James Beattie",
"Duncan MacGregor Crerar" };
String Poems1[] = { "", "Tam O Shanter", "Auld Lang Syne" };
String Poems2[] = { "", "Judgement Of Paris", "The Minstrel" };
String Poems3[] = { "", "A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns",
"My Bonnie Rowan Tree" };

TextView selectedPoem; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// set to fullscreen mode
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// set content view
setContentView(R.layout.poet);

initialize(); // call this method
}

public void initialize() {

// initializing items that are in the class
PoetSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoet);
PoemSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPoem);
// Hide the second spinner
PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
selectedPoem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedPoem);
// setting up array adapters
//
// for each spinner
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
  .createFromResource(this, R.array.poet_arrays,
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
PoetSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
PoetSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

PoemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Object poem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if("Tam O Shanter".equals(poem.toString())){
         selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.tamO));
    }
    if("Auld Lang Syne".equals(poem.toString())){
     selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.auld));
   }
    if("Judgement Of Paris".equals(poem.toString())){
     selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.judgement));
   }
    if("The Minstrel".equals(poem.toString())){
     selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.minstrel));
   }
    if("A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns".equals(poem.toString())){
     selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.rob));
   }
    if("My Bonnie Rowan Tree".equals(poem.toString())){
     selectedPoem.setText(getString(R.string.row));
   }

  }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
});
}

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
long id) {
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = null;
switch (pos) {
  case 1:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  case 2:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  case 3:
  adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.poem_arrays3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  break;
  default:
  // Hide the poem spinner
  PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  break;
}

if (adapter != null) {
  // Set the poem spinners content and show the spinner
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  PoemSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  PoemSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

the XML file

```
    <string name="tamO">
But pleasures are like poppies spread, 
You seize the flower, its bloom is shed; 
Or like the snow falls in the river, 
A moment white--then melts for ever; 
Or like the borealis race, 
That flit ere you can point their place; 
Or like the rainbow\'s lovely form 
Evanishing amid the storm.-- 
Nae man can tether time or tide; 
The hour approaches Tam maun ride; 
That hour, o\' night\'s black arch the key-stane, 
That dreary hour he mounts his beast in; 
And sic a night he taks the road in 
As ne\'er poor sinner was abroad in.
</string>
<string name="auld">
For auld lang syne, my dear, 
For auld lang syne. 
We\'ll tak a cup o\' kindness yet, 
For auld lang syne. 

And surely ye\'ll be your pint stowp! 
And surely I\'ll be mine! 
And we\'ll tak a cup o\'kindness yet, 
For auld lang syne. 

We twa hae run about the braes, 
And pou\'d the gowans fine; 
But we\'ve wander\'d mony a weary fit, 
Sin\' auld lang syne. 
</string>
<string name="judgement">
Up the broad cliffs, that tower\'d immense to heaven,
Green wav\'d the lofty pines, on every side;
Save where, fair-opening to the beam of even,
A dale sloped gradual to the valley wide.

Echoed the vale with many a chearful note;
The various lowe of herds resounding long,
The shrilling pipe, the mellow horn remote,
And social clamours of the festive throng.

For now, low-hovering o\'er the western main, 
Where amber clouds begirt his dazzling throne,
The sun with ruddier verdure deck\'d the plain;
And lakes, and streams, and spires triumphal shone;
</string>
<string name="minstrel">
    Of chance or change O let not man complain,
Else shall he never never cease to wail:
For, from th\' imperial dome, to where the swain
Rears the lone cottage in the silent dale,
All feel th\' assault of fortune\'s fickle gale;
Art, empire, earth itself, to change are doom\'d;
Earthquakes have raised to heaven the humble vale,
And gulphs the mountain\'s mighty mass entomb\'d,
And where th\' Atlantick rolls wide continents have bloom\'d.

But sure to foreign climes we need not range,
Nor search the antient records of our race,
To learn the dire effects of time and change,
Which in ourselves, alas, we daily trace.
Yet at the darken\'d eye, the wither\'d face,
Or hoary hair, I never will repine:
But spare, O Time, whate\'er of mental grace,
Of candour, love, or sympathy divine,
Whate\'er of fancy\'s ray, or friendship\'s flame is mine.
</string>  
<string name="rob">
He touched our country\’s ancient harp
With truest patriotic fire;
Forth thrilling came soul-stirring strains,
Man\’s nobler actions to inspire.
The cottar\’s fireside, \‘neath his spell,
Becomes at once a hallowed shrine;
His  hymn to Mary swells the heart,
And fills the eye his Auld Lang Syne.

Not to his native land alone
His genius and his fame belong,
In other climes is treasured dear
His matchless legacy of song.
His melodies have echoing gone
To continents and isles afar;
 They  cheer and gladden hearts alike
\‘Neath Southern Cross and Polar Star.

</string>

<string name="row">
Thrice welcome sweet green spray
Culled from my Rowan Tree,  
By loved ones far away,
In Bonnie Amulree.

 In Boyhood\’s days thy root
Was planted by my hand;
Just ere I left my dear,
My Scottish fatherland.

Thou but a sapling then,
Though now a sheltering tree,
While warblers in thy boughs,
Sing sweetest melodies.
</string>

<string-array name="film_arrays">
    <item>Please Select...</item>
    <item>Sean Connery</item>
    <item>Billy Connolly</item>
    <item>James McAvoy</item>
    <item>Karen Gillan</item>
    <item>Kelly Macdonald</item>
    <item>Ashley Jensen</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="poet_arrays">
    <item>Please Select...</item>
    <item>Robert Burns</item>
    <item>James Beattie</item>
    <item>Duncan MacGregor Crerar</item>
</string-array>

    <string-array name="poem_arrays1">
    <item>Please Select...</item>
    <item>Tam O Shanter</item>
    <item>Auld Lang Syne</item>
</string-array> 
    <string-array name="poem_arrays2">
    <item>Please Select...</item>
    <item>Judgment Of Paris</item>
    <item>The Minstrel</item>
</string-array>
    <string-array name="poem_arrays3">
    <item>Please Select a...</item>
    <item>A Poem Commemorating Robbie Burns</item>
    <item>My Bonnie Rowan Tree</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Please post the content of your array files

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You say the string is "judgement" but the poem is "Judgement Of Paris". How do they tie together?

Comment: @Squonk  Because it is if the string is equal to "Judgement of paris" then it sets the text to judgment.  makes sense.

Comment: Obviously the content of the poet spinner is populated from array xml files so please post the poet_arrays file

Comment: @Thomas : My point is a string in the `/res/values` directory should look something like `<string name="user_prefs_name">UserPrefs</string>
` (for example). All you put in your question is `string name="judgement"` which doesn't tell us anything. There isn't anything obviously wrong with your code and, as you say, all the other choices work. Remember Java is case-sensitive so check through everything but if there are still problems, post your `strings.xml` file.

Comment: @Squonk  I have updated it with the XML file.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if you think it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing

Judgment Of Paris (poem_arrays2) to

Judgement Of Paris (code).

The two strings are obviously different.

BTW I would really consider using a database instead of hard-coded strings in xml files.
A database would give you a design that prevents bugs like this from happening. It's also much more generic and extendable. If you have more poets and/or poems just add them to your tables without changing any code.
Or you could use an xml file that reflects the hierarchy of your entities, something like this:

```
<poet name="Robert Burns">
    <poem name="Tam O Shanter">
        But pleasures are like poppies spread, 
        [...] 
    </poem>
    <poem name="Auld Lang Syne">
        For auld lang syne, my dear,
        [...] 
    </poem>
</poet>
```